# C# System.Data.SqlClient Insert and saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a page for my user with textboxes (or something else) where the user can fill in the textboxes, press add. This needs to safe the information to the database. 
I'm trying to do this with System.Data.SqlClient; But it won't work.
Could you help me?

The controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DNDB.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace DNDB.Controllers
{
public class DomeinnaamController : Controller
{
    // GET: Domeinnaam
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var entities = new DomeinnaambeheerEntities1();

        return View(entities.Domeinnaam.ToList());
    }



    public ActionResult CreateDomainName()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateDomainName(Domeinnaam model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter.Update(DomeinnaambeheerEntities1.Tables["Domeinnaam"]);
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Er is een fout opgetreden bij het update  van de tabel.");
            }

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
}
```

Index Page:

@model IEnumerable

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/StyleSheet.css")
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Domeinnaam Overzicht</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Voeg toe", "CreateDomainName") 


<table id="tabledomeinnamen">
<tr>
    <th>    
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActief) 
    </th>
    <th> 
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Naam) 
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TLD)
    </th>
    <th>    
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DatumRegistratie)
    </th> 
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Omschrijving)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DatumOpzeg)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EigenaarID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Opmerking)
    </th>
    <th> 
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BeheerAccountID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.KlantID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegistrarID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BetaaldVan)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BetaaldTot)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AfspraakPrijs)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@Html.Partial("PartDomeinnaam", Model)


</table>
```

The Partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<DNDB.Models.Domeinnaam>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActief)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Naam)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TLD)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatumRegistratie)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Omschrijving)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DatumOpzeg)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EigenaarID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Opmerking)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BeheerAccountID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KlantID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegistrarID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BetaaldVan)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BetaaldTot)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AfspraakPrijs)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID })
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID })
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

On this page I need the code to add the information to the database:

```
@model DNDB.Models.Domeinnaam

@Styles.Render("~/Content/StyleSheet.css")
@{
ViewBag.Title = "CreateDomainName";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>CreateDomainName</title>
</head>
<body>

    <label>IsActief</label>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsActief) 
    <label>Naam</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Naam)
    <label>TLD</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TLD)
    <label>DatumRegistratie</label><br />   
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatumRegistratie)
    <label>Omschrijving</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Omschrijving)
    <label>OpzegDatum</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatumOpzeg)
    <label>EigenaarID</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EigenaarID)
    <label>Opmerking</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Opmerking)
    <label>BeheerAccountID</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BeheerAccountID)
    <label>KlantID</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.KlantID)
    <label>RegistrarID</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrarID)
    <label>BetaaldVan</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BetaaldVan)
    <label>BetaaldTot</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BetaaldTot)
    <label>Prijsafspraak</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AfspraakPrijs)
    <br />

</body>
</html>

<input type="submit" value="add">
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work? what errors are you getting?

Comment: Which part it doesn't work? I don't very familiar in "Hollandsche spreken", but I can figure out what's wrong if you provide error details.

Comment: @Harry I just do not know how to code this part. My question if some one can help me with the coding. I'm new to programming so I find it hard.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I just do not know how to code this part. My question if some one can help me with the coding. I'm new to programming so I find it hard.

Comment: It would help, if you read up on saving information to a database based article in c#. and that should guide you. no one here will do your work for you. at least have to attempt it :)

Comment: @Harry I'll add the code that I got. You will laugh but maybe then you can help me

Comment: Not makes sense in your code. The model in your view is  `IEnumerable<Domeinnaam>`, but you creating manual inputs that have no relationship to that model. And then the POST method expects a single instance of `Domeinnaam`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thats why I ask for help. I find this hard.

Comment: If that view is for returned for the `CreateDomainName()` GET method, then its `@model Domeinnaam` and you use the `HtmlHelper` method to bind to you model - `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Naam) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Naam) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Naam)` etc

Answer (score 1):

Use Html Helpers to bind model

```
<label>IsActief</label>
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.isActief)
<br /> 
<label>Naam</label><br />
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.name)
```

Same for the others and remove `IENumerable` from the top

Comment: Can you please share your view and model  Data . So i can figure out

Comment: I added my index page to the post

Comment: on my index page this errors now. @foreach (var item in Model) {

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DNDB.Models.Domeinnaam' because 'DNDB.Models.Domeinnaam' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' DNDB C:\Users\marijn\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DNDB\DNDB\Views\Domeinnaam\Index.cshtml 60 Active

Comment: You cannot use two different types of Model in same view i.e IEnumberable<model> and @model

Comment: Use a partial view to render the foreach part

Comment: Okay, but why doesn't my information get added to the DB

Comment: Uhm, as I said. I'm kind off new to programming. Can you explain a bit more of that partial view part :)

Comment: Partial view are rendered inside a parent view.

Comment: inside Views->Domeinnaam .RIght Click on Domeinnaam->Add->View->Check Create a partial View

Comment: Add You Foreach inside Partial View   and Add @model IEnumberable<DNDB.Models.Domeinnaam>3

Comment: And In Your Index Page in place of foreach write @Html.Partial("PartialViewName",Model)

Comment: added the code to the file. I'm getting errors on my DomeinnaamController page, It says: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0117 'DomeinnaambeheerEntities1' does not contain a definition for 'Tables' DNDB C:\Users\marijn\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DNDB\DNDB\Controllers\DomeinnaamController.cs 36 Active

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context DNDB C:\Users\marijn\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DNDB\DNDB\Controllers\DomeinnaamController.cs 40 Active

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning CS0168 The variable 'e' is declared but never used DNDB C:\Users\marijn\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DNDB\DNDB\Controllers\DomeinnaamController.cs 38 Active

Comment: my guess is that on my Controller page there is something wrong with the Sqladapter.Update